# JQuery Mobile - Custom listview height changes on click

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile listview with a custom item height (50px). Whenever the item is clicked, its height changes. How can I fixate the custom height?

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/3gnvhxth/6/**

I am using JQuery Mobile v1.45 and JQuery 1.11.1.

Before click:
[image: Before click]

After click:
[image: After click]

HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li class="custom_item">
        <a class="custom_link" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
            <img class="custom_image" src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1">
            Click Item 1
        </a>   
    </li>
        <a class="custom_link" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
            <img class="custom_image" src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2">
            Click Item 2
        </a>   
    </li>
    <li class="custom_item">
        <a class="custom_link" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
            <img class="custom_image" src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3">
            Click Item 3
        </a>   
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.custom_item {
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
.custom_link {
    padding-left: 50px !important;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
.custom_image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis is right about the min-height from the jQM CSS file.  You need to override it, but also remove top and bottom padding on the link as that causes the height issue on click:

```
.custom_link {
    padding-left: 50px !important;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    height: 50px;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3gnvhxth/9/)**

Setting line-height keeps the text vertically centered. If that is not important to you, just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a default min-height in your css that causing the problem

**CSS**

```
.ui-listview > .ui-li-has-thumb > .ui-btn, .ui-listview > .ui-li-static.ui-li-has-thumb {
    min-height: 3.625em; // Remove this or adjust to your needs
    padding-left: 6.25em;
}
```

Comment: min-height + padding + line-height. upvoted, see ezanker for full answer